# No output in right channel audio headphones

Tags: mac, audio

The right channel output cuts off and on when using headphones. The laptop speakers work fine.

I have tried 3 known working headphones, a USB headset (connected via USB not using the audio jack), cleaning out the audio jack, nothing fixes the problem.

The only fix I have discovered so far is twisting and moving the cords for all the headphones I have used, only problem with that is all these headphones work fine with other devices such as a PS3 a different PC ...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is an electronics issue. Its probably a single wire (the one wire that carries the right channel sound).

There is little that you can do about this unless you know how to solder/feel comfortable doing this repair yourself.

I would suggest checking if your computer is still under warranty and if it is having apple take a look at it. That should likely be covered.

Comment: This is what I thought it could be ... and there is no way apple would fix this since the laptop is a Thinkpad T60 :) and even then the warranty expired years ago.

Comment: Ahh. Sorry assumed because its the Apple forum. You could try Lenovo Tech Suport.

Comment: I'm running 10.6.8 and want to determine if it could be a possible OS problem ... now that I have done more testing when using a USB device it doesn't matter what USB port I plug into the issue is still there ... strange

Comment: Ok, I apologize for my my quick response, you are having the same trouble even when connecting a headset through usb completely bypassing the audio jack?

Comment: That is correct